What's the disease affecting my cucumbers?
I noticed today that some of my cucumber's newer leaves are blackened and withered around the edges, and the new flowers seem to be similarly affected (they blacken and die before they can bloom). The older leaves also have some holes and white spots on them. Does anyone know what disease is affecting them? For reference this is in the bay area, weather is very warm and pretty dry.



I do not know the exact cause, but the first photos points me to fertilizer problem (too little or too much). Boron? No experience on such thing on cucumbers, so wild guess, So could you give us some details on soil and fertilization (and maybe what you had in the plot last years)

@GiacomoCatenazzi Grew cucumbers there the previous year as well (without any problems). I fertilized the soil before planting the seedlings down this year (with 10-10-10 fertilizer I think? the most common type you find at home depot), but never since then. I took a look at a nutrient deficiency chart for cucumbers, but it doesn't seem like the blackening is associated with any in particular. The cucumbers that are growing also seem to yellow prematurely. Thanks for the help!
